# Cross-Platform PDF reader and editor?

Tags: pdf, crossplatform

I constantly switch between Windows and Ubuntu and I usually add comments and/or bookmarks in my PDF documents. Now I'm using Adobe PDF and Okular, but the bookmarks, comments and highlighting are not compatible at all, so I only can use them in one of them, having to change the system everytime I need to add something when I'm in Ubuntu.

Okular apparently is in Windows too, but I haven't seen anything more than a mention in the official page. Some ideas? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Master PDF Editor](https://code-industry.net/get-masterpdfeditor/), or [FoxitReader](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/) to do this. The first, will grant to you more functionalities, like objects manipulation, similar to [PhantomPDF](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-editor/) from Foxit.

Answer (score 1):

Our software PDF Studio works on Linux, Windows and Mac and is compatible with Adobe PDF specs on all platforms so you can switch back and forth between OSes.

https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudio/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with FLOSS Software on Linux. Okular annotations are compatible with Adobe, when correctly used.

You have to use File → Save to save it over the current file or File → Save As... to save it to a new file in order to save annotations in Okular.

https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kdegraphics/okular/annotations.html